# My Dll Forms Still Show Boarders Even Though i Set It To None

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

When i am designing my dll This is how i have designed it to look, [Visual Design of one of my dll forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWhCb.png)

But when i reference the built dll to a deperate program and try and run it. it looks like this.
[Dll Form Now has boarders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VySWd.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have property in `System.Windows.Forms.Form` called `FormBorderStyle`. Default is Sizable. You can set here what ever you want.
Also, you can set border programmatically in constructor of that form:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```